# How to show only a selected part of a web view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am wondering how to show only a selected portion of a web view in a swift app. I managed to view the content of a url using web view kit in swift, but I noticed that it is no different then if I opened it in the safari app on my phone. I don't want any of the links or anything from the sidebars from the website, mostly just the meat of the page.

An example of what I am trying to do is something like a wikipedia reader. The app looks like a tableview with just a random assortment of links to wikipedia, and when someone presses the cell it takes them to that specific wikipedia and shows only the first big paragraph of that wikipedia.

I was thinking it was possible that when the tableview cell is pressed it opens a new view controller with that first paragraph, the problem I am having is figuring out how to access that specific portion from the url.

As a sidenote, the wikipedia is just an example, i do not need a link to their api that has all this.

If i can answer any questions you have i will do so to the best of my ability. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really more of a web development question. The behaviour you are describing with Wikipedia is because their website is optimized for mobile, which means the website displays differently when shown on a mobile device vs a browser. This is the case for many many modern websites.

Therefore to achieve what you need, the website you are trying to access needs to be 'mobile responsive'.

Comment: no problem, please mark it as the answer if you're satisfied